# VS 2010 - Import Export Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Everytime I open VS 2010 I get this:

> The automatically saved settings file 'visual studio 2010\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings' is not available for write. You can change this file on the 'Import and Export Settings' Tools Options page.

Great ok. I'll export what i've got out and move it to a new location, and then set that as the location to look for the settings file.

**Step 1: Fail**

Import and Export Settings Wizard > Export selected environment settings > next > next > Dialog dissappears with no information on any file being stored anywhere.

**Step 2: Fail**

Manually find old `CurrentSettings.vssettings` file. Copy to new location e.g. `C:\VSSettings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`

Tools > Options > Environment > Import and Export Settings > Automatically save my settings to this file:

Change location to `C:\VSSettings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`

> The specified path for the auto-save settings file is invalid.  Please enter a valid path.

Clicking on the browse button does nothing. Something has screwed up here, obviously because it couldn't get to the location where my settings WERE being stored.

**Step 3:** ?
How to fix this up

I would prefer to not have to reset my settings because it IS loading some of them from soemwhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to reset settings.

Happened because a mapped drive didn't map and corrupted the Import and Export Settings Wizard.

Answer (score 15):

This command will reset the settings if you're having trouble with the GUI. This will work  going back to at least 2005--as long as you change the path accordingly, of course :)

```
"%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /resetuserdata
```

Also see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/11/22/496098.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me: (in VS 2013)

```
1. Go to Tools > Options
2. Go to Environment > "Import and Export Settings" 
3. Change the path to existing one
```

Source [blog.icsharp.net](http://blog.icsharp.net/2013/07/CurrentSettings-vssettings-cannot-be-found.html)

Comment: This works in VS 2017 as well.  Mine had something to do with my documents folder being synced to a network share.  VS didn't know what to do.  By specifying the folder it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is working Perfectly

1.Click Start and run or type "run" in search box of Start menu

2.Then double click the run and you should type `cmd` and open command prompt.

3.Then copy and paste the below command in command prompt -> Click <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

```
%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /resetuserdata
```