# visual studio 2010 startup issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My visual studio 2010 is throwing an error like **"The Operation Could not be Completed"** during startup.I tried reinstalling it but the same problem exists.Now when i delete the Visual Studio 2010 folder in MyDocuments,its opening but with the following error

```
     The Automatically saved settings file 'C:\documents and settings\admin\MyDocuments\visual studio 2010\settings\Currentsettings.Vssettings' cannot be found.You can Change this file on the 'Import and export settings' Tools option page.The IDE will use your most recent settings for this session.
```

when i click **ok** my vs2010 is opening up.How can i correct this error.please give your suggestions guys....

Comment: Goto `Tools` -> `Import and Export Settings` -> `Reset All Settings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i believe is going on is that the installation of visual studio took place on another user on that machine with more elevated rights and it has the path set to a folder that can not be accessed from this user. Or your rights on your windows are somehow messed up.

Eider way, what you can do is just point VS to another folder on a partition where it will store the projects.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/34c29fes(v=vs.100).aspx -- change the location of your projects to a folder on your drive somewhere. ie create one.

Comment: i think you`ll have to give us a little more information than "it`s not working". Did you manage to set the path? If you did, how did VS react to that?

Comment: As i said before its showing the same error...like "The Operation Could not be Completed" and  if i delete the Visual Studio 2010 folder in MyDocuments its showing the above said error

Comment: try: Tools>Settings>Import and Export Settings>Reset all settings

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624073/vs-2010-import-export-settings