# The automatically saved setting file couldn't be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just moved a project from one pc to another which btw is in Company Workgroup but I am unable to open the project as it shows some errors:

1) on startup:

The automatically saved setting file is not available for write. when I go to 'Import and Export Setting' I don't know what to put there

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4eLR.png)

2) after VS is running and I try to reload the project:

Creation of the virtual directory failed

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwxh1.png)

I will really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS 2010 - Import Export Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624073/vs-2010-import-export-settings)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config help?

Comment: Solved the problem by deleting files in:

C:\Users\*UserName*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio

deleted them, rebooted the PC and restored them.

It sounds weird to me but somehow It worked.

Anyway I appreciate your help. Mr Wills!